# Permission denied error while installing gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab

While installing gitlab ci (continues integration) on ubuntu (12.04LTS) i get the following error in step 5 (Setup application)

from: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md

```
root@s2:~# cd /home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci/
root@s2:/home/gitlab_ci/gitlab-ci# sudo -u gitlab_ci -H gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

It seems these gems try to install outside /home/gitlab_ci which indeed would fail as user gitlab_ci

My question is - are these instructions wrong? - or - am i an edge case.
And offcourse how would I safely solve this problem, just running the command as root might give me more trouble later on...

Extra information, Ruby was originally installed for gitlab itself and that works fine.

Comment: So step 2 was completed? (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md#2-install-ruby-rvm-for-gitlab_ci): was ruby installed elsewhere then /usr/local/... ?

Comment: Why not follow the same process than https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#2-ruby, and compile ruby for user `gitlab_ci`, like you did for user `gitlab`? (making sure the `$PATH` will find the *local* ruby before the system one)

Comment: I should clarify: I have gitlab installed prior to this attempt to install gitlab-ci. With that Ruby came to my system, i have no idea where it installed but I presume the default location.

Comment: ok. I prefer compiling my ruby and installing it *within my `gitlab` account* (as opposed to letting it install in the default `/usr` system path)

Comment: so i either need to tell gitlab-ci that it should not use ruby from /usr/local (as it is indended i guess) or i should let gitlab-ci use the now allready installed ruby from /usr/local. How do I do either?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that [gitlab installation step 2](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#2-ruby) proposes to recompile ruby, I usually compile it with a `--prefix=/home/gitlab/ruby1.9.3` argument, in order to use a ruby in which I have full rights to write/add any gem I want without using `sudo`.

So the `$PATH` used by the gitlab_ci account should include `/home/gitlab/ruby1.9.3/bin` and any gem installed by that account would go into the local compiled ruby.
If both accounts are part of the same group, they should both be able to write into `/home/gitlab/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`.